# Connecting to a database through RMySQL package in R 3.0.2

Tags: r, data-analysis, rmysql

I'm trying to connect to the ucsc genome server and then trying to select a database hg19 in it.

Method I already know(works perfectly fine):

```
hg19 <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="genome",db="hg19",host="genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
```

Alternative Method I wish to know:

```
ucscDb <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user = "genome",host = "genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
```

Now, *is there any way to use query such as **use hg19;** to select the database hg19 through the connection handle ucscDb?*

The difference b/w the two methods is the use of db argument within the dbConnect function.

In the **former**, I specify the db in the arguments themselves.
In the **latter**, I just connect to the ucsc server and then try to work on hg19 database through queries may be using dbGetQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

The `dbConnect` command requires a db parameter.  It sets the default schema for the connection  However, there is no rule that in your `dbSendQuery` command you have to utilize the default schema.  For example, if you connect with

```
hg19 <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="genome",db="hg19",host="genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
```

but maybe want to query against a database called "hg18".  You could simple run the following:

```
query = dbSendQuery(hg19, "SELECT * FROM hg18.sometable);
hg18Data = fetch(query, n=-1);
```